# SQL Server : query with subquery involving select from previous selection

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a query in SQL Server to determine how many times a person's name shows up in a list, but also that list will be unknown, so I would have to get the actual name from the previous select index... It's hard to explain so I'll show the query first and hopefully someone can help.

```
SELECT 
    SpeakerName, Spoken,
    (SELECT COUNT(SpeakerName)
     FROM tbl_SpeakerCard_Log
     WHERE SpeakerName = 'SpeakerName[i]' AND SpeakDate = '3-9-16') as TimesSpoken
FROM 
    tbl_SpeakerCard_Log
WHERE 
    AID = ####
ORDER BY 
    GeneralComment ASC
```

So basically, in `SpeakerName[i]`, I'd like to somehow get the `SpeakerName` from the outer `Select`. The output should come out something like this

```
+-------------+--------+-------------+
| SpeakerName | Spoken | TimesSpoken |
+-------------+--------+-------------+
| Holly       |      0 |           4 |
| Robert      |      1 |           5 |
| Mike        |      1 |           2 |
+-------------+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: Have you tried to add aliases to the tables?

Comment: This looks like a simple GROUP BY with COUNT(*) to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count number of occurrences for each unique value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13235981/count-number-of-occurrences-for-each-unique-value)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select x.SpeakerName, x.Spoken, COUNT(*) as TimesSpoken
from tbl_SpeakerCard_Log x
WHERE AID = ####
and x.SpeakDate = '3-9-16'
group by x.SpeakerName, x.Spoken
```

Don't have SSMS installed on this computer so can't test it.